# Как реализовать падающие буквы с верхней строки экрана?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, gui, pygame

Как сделать так, чтобы буквы падали по одной в случайной точки верхней строки экрана.

**main.py**:

```
import pygame
from random import choice, randrange, randint
import sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


# Константы
RES = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1600, 900
FONT_SIZE = 40
FPS = 60
SPEED = 5
X = randint(0, WIDTH)
Y = 0

#  классы\функции
class Letter():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
    
        english = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
             'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

        c = choice(english)

        # self.ascii = symbol
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('ms mincho', FONT_SIZE, bold=True)
        if c == 'a':
            font_render_c = font.render('a', True, (128, 128, 128))
            self.screen.blit(font_render_c, (X, Y))
        elif c== 'b':
            font_render_c = font.render('b', True, (128, 128, 128))
            self.screen.blit(font_render_c, (X, Y))
        elif c== 'c':
            font_render_c = font.render('c', True, (128, 128, 128))
            self.screen.blit(font_render_c, (X, Y))
        elif c== 'e':
            font_render_c = font.render('e', True, (128, 128, 128))
            self.screen.blit(font_render_c, (X, Y))
        elif c== 'f':
            font_render_c = font.render('f', True, (128, 128, 128))
            self.screen.blit(font_render_c, (X, Y))
        elif c== 'g':
            font_render_c = font.render('g', True, (128, 128, 128))

            self.screen.blit(font_render_c, (X, Y))


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RES)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while True:
    # Задержка
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Цикл обработки событий
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    Y = Y + SPEED
    if Y > HEIGHT:
        X = randrange(0, WIDTH) 
        Y = -25
    Letter(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import os
import pygame as pg
from random import choice, randrange


class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.speed = speed
        self.value = choice(green_katakana)
        self.interval = randrange(5, 30)

    def draw(self, color):
        frames = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if not frames % self.interval:
            self.value = choice(green_katakana if color == 'green' 
                                             else lightgreen_katakana)
        self.y = self.y + self.speed if self.y < HEIGHT else -FONT_SIZE
        surface.blit(self.value, (self.x, self.y))


class SymbolColumn:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.column_height = randrange(8, 24)
        self.speed = randrange(3, 7)
        self.symbols = [
            Symbol(x, i, self.speed) for i in 
                range(y, y - FONT_SIZE * self.column_height, -FONT_SIZE)
        ]

    def draw(self):
        [symbol.draw('green') if i else symbol.draw('lightgreen') 
            for i, symbol in enumerate(self.symbols)]


os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
RES = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1600, 900
FONT_SIZE = 40
alpha_value = 0

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode(RES)
surface = pg.Surface(RES)
surface.set_alpha(alpha_value)
clock = pg.time.Clock()

katakana = [chr(int('0x30a0', 16) + i) for i in range(96)]

font = pg.font.Font('font/ms mincho.ttf', FONT_SIZE, bold=True)         #! MS Mincho.ttf

green_katakana = [font.render(char, True, (40, randrange(160, 256), 40)) 
                                   for char in katakana]
lightgreen_katakana = [font.render(char, True, pg.Color('lightgreen')) 
                                   for char in katakana]

symbol_columns = [SymbolColumn(x, randrange(-HEIGHT, 0)) 
                                   for x in range(0, WIDTH, FONT_SIZE)]

while True:
    screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
    surface.fill(pg.Color('black'))

    [symbol_column.draw() for symbol_column in symbol_columns]

    if not pg.time.get_ticks() % 20 and alpha_value < 170:
        alpha_value += 6
        surface.set_alpha(alpha_value)

    [exit() for i in pg.event.get() if i.type == pg.QUIT]
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Egor что не так?